# How to pull the non delimited date and time out of a string

Tags: php, regex

I need to pull the date and time out of this string: `some_report_20161005_1530.xml` so I can reformat it to something more work-with-able. The date and time will change from file to file, but will always stay in this format: `some_report_{year}{month}{day}_{24hr time}.xml`

```
$test = 'some_report_20161005_1530.xml';
preg_match('(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{4})', $test, $test_matches);
print_r( $test_matches );
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

(Forgive my ignorance or misuse of these functions. I am by no means an expert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `some_report` doesn't contain digits, the date and time parts are already in a good order to work in the DateTime constructor, so you can extract them with a simpler regex.

```
$date_time = new DateTime(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $your_string));
```

Comment: The additional `1530` numbers are being treated as hour and minute, could have unintended side effects.

Comment: Oh, I thought they were supposed to be hour and minute?

Comment: You're right. I misread the question, thought he only wanted the date. In that case, this is a slick way to do it. =)

Comment: Thanks! The question body does only say date, but based on the title I assumed OP just forgot to say time as well.

Comment: Modified question to include time. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ExcellentSP No problem. I had considered editing it myself, but I wasn't _sure_ that my assumption was correct.

Answer (score 2):

One simple regex approach would be to pull out the 8 and 4 digit numbers:

```
preg_match("/(\d{8})_(\d{4})/", $filename, $matches);

array_shift($matches);
list($date, $time) = $matches;
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/npGC8

Or you could just use `explode` and skip the regex:

```
list($name1, $name2, $date, $time) = explode("_", str_replace(".","_", $filename));
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/lAvTN

Then it's as simple as handing it to `DateTime`, such that you can manipulate or format however you want.

```
$dt = new DateTime($date . $time);

echo $dt->format('n/j/y h:ia'); // 10/5/16 03:30pm
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$test = 'some_report_20161005_1530.xml';

echo  preg_replace('#(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(_)(\d{2})(\d{2})#', 
                   '${1}-${2}-${3}_${5}:${6}', $test) , '<br/>';

preg_match(
 '#(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})(_)(?<hour>\d{2})(?<minute>\d{2})#', 
 $test,$test_matches);

print_r( $test_matches );
```

Just examples...